# How do I load a Javascript which contains document.write multiple times in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

I have a javascript code presented in the head tag:

```
document.write('<script>..</script><style>..</style><a></a><script src".."></script>');
```

The code inside the `document.write()` is actually an html document of a sample webpage with `scripts` , `styles` , `metas` and all other possible elements.

Now i need to run this javascript code each time in any element where `sample-js-doc` attribute tag is presented in the `body`. For example: `<div sample-js-doc ></div>` or `<a sample-js-doc ></a>`

Currently, where-ever I place the javascrit, the content loads there quickly. That's look good. But I need it also to be invoked in other places where `sample-js-doc` attribute tag is present.

How do I modify the javascript code to achieve this without removing all other elements present in the webpage?

Answer (score 1):

Use `querySelectorAll`

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('[sample-js-doc]');

for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].innerHTML = '<script>..</script><style>..</style><a></a><script src".."></script>';
}
```

Comment: Using `.innerHTML` for `scripts` and all doesn't work at all.